# Are there any organisms that do not respire?

Tags: respiration

I am not talking about not needing oxygen. I understand that there are organisms that do not need oxygen. I am asking if there are any organisms that do not respire. (Eg, only ferment) I would like to ask if there are any such organisms?

Edit:
Google searches show two contradicting points of view, as shown [here](https://sciencing.com/type-organisms-use-cellular-respiration-6402415.html) and [here](https://socratic.org/questions/what-types-of-organisms-undergo-cellular-respiration)

Comment: Homework questions are expected to show some prior research.

Comment: This is a genuine question, I am not doing any homework. I have done Google searches but nothing quite gives me the answer I am looking for (all answers relating to anaerobic respiration)

Comment: "homework" is not about the legitimacy of the question but the simplicity, simple questions are expected to show prior research to prevent mass asking of simple questions like homework questions. just edit your question to show some prior research and it will be fine. what and how did you research and what did you find and why is it not enough.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your suggestion! I have edited the post. Hopefully this is better!

Comment: Please state in (bio)chemical terms what you mean by “respire” and what you mean by “ferment”. Then everyone will be clear what you are asking. It may even enable you to find the answer yourself.

Answer (score 4):

One example of a nonrespiring organism would be [lactic acid bacteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lactic_acid_bacteria)

They're (nonrespiring) obligate anaerobes.

They don't respire, since they can't use an **external** compund (oxygen, nitrate, sulfur, iron, etc.) as a *terminal electron acceptor*. They instead use an **internal** *terminal electron acceptor* (e.g. Pyruvate). That requires constant regeneration of NAD. Lactic Acid Bacteria regenerate NAD by oxidizing Pyruvate to lactic acid. [See this](https://bio.libretexts.org/Courses/University_of_California_Davis/BIS_2A%3A_Introductory_Biology_(Easlon)/Readings/09.3%3A_Fermentation_and_Regeneration_of_NAD)

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about organism that ferment, then you have LABs (described in markur's answer).

I am interpreting your question as you are asking an organism that is [aerotolerant anaerobe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerotolerant_anaerobe) (organism that cannot use oxygen but tolerate its presence). In that case, *[Cutibacterium acnes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutibacterium_acnes)* is an example.

Also, scientist recently discovered a multicellular animal that doesn't breath at all. A parasite named *[Henneguya salminicola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henneguya_zschokkei)* having less than 10 cells hides in the muscles of salmon and does not breath oxygen. It is the only animal with no mitochondrial genome (a crucial portion of DNA stored in mitochondria that includes genes responsible for respiration). More about it in [this article](https://www.livescience.com/first-non-breathing-animal.html).